# Simple HTML Dom , how to avoid external links when parsing (without avoiding links without host url)

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

Im attempting to build a scraper to fetch all the links, i want to avoid external links so I have the following code...

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {

      if (!in_array($element->href, $outputedUrls) && strpos($element->href, 'www.example.ie') !== false ) {
        echo 'LEVEL 1: '.$element->href . '<br>';
        $outputedUrls[] = $element->href;

        get_links($element->href,$outputedUrls,1);
      }

 }
```

The problem is, it works too well, it doesnt include links that dont have the main url in the `href` , e.g. if a on the homepage is simply `<a href="activities">activities</a>` this wont get included.

How do I both insure external links arent included, but links that are part of the website ARE included. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check regex for subdomain as well.. That will resolve the issue to certain extent

```
if(preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i", $subdomain)) {
   echo "Valid sub domain";
  }else{
   echo "Not a valid sub domain.";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you , but my only issue there is that I've been reading a bit and it seems the general consensus is that you shouldnt use regex for this kind of stuff? Or am I picking that up incorrectly

Comment: I really admire your research but sometimes it is better to simplify the things. Only issue with that it is bit slow but you can use some better regex library like [link] http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php that will solve this issue to certain extend. You can find many other as well